# Cannot block specific websites

Tags: macos, admin

I've been able to block Youtube and Facebook sites, but not amazon or google. Why? Seems these two websites have something different. Thanks

```
Bernardos-MacBook-Pro:~ bernardo$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
127.0.0.1 http://www.amazon.es
127.0.0.1 https://www.google.es
127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it without `http://` like on facebook and youtube